# Change the name of class of div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written below lines of code

```
        $(document).ready(function()
        {

           $('.btn-custom').click(function() { 
              var id = $(this).attr('id');
              $('.btn-custom').addClass('.btn-custom-primary');
              $("#"+id).addClass('btn-custom-selected');
           });
           ...
         });
```

The html of these custom buttons are rendered in browser as

```
      <div id="rooms-information" class="form-group">
      <div id="3ccd3803-a8ba-0328-cf9d-28bb72abbcae" class="btn-custom btn-custom-primary col-md-4 room-no-6"><div class="room-info-section"><span>Room No.: 6</span><br><span id="room0">Deluxe</span></div><div class="capacity-info"><span>Total Capacity: 8</span><br><span>Available: 8</span></div></div>
      <div id="4908ec27-b2ca-7bf7-de3d-83181d5c41a6" class="btn-custom btn-custom-primary col-md-4 room-no-1"><div class="room-info-section"><span>Room No.: 1</span><br><span id="room1">Deluxe</span></div><div class="capacity-info"><span>Total Capacity: 4</span><br><span>Available: 4</span></div></div>
      <div id="531709a7-6bc2-ddbe-3f3d-1642b7d70929" class="btn-custom btn-custom-primary col-md-4 room-no-3"><div class="room-info-section"><span>Room No.: 3</span><br><span id="room2">Simple</span></div><div class="capacity-info"><span>Total Capacity: 4</span><br><span>Available: 4</span></div></div>
      <div id="cac24d40-0e85-6707-9797-5f9f3449ecf8" class="btn-custom btn-custom-primary col-md-4 room-no-4"><div class="room-info-section"><span>Room No.: 4</span><br><span id="room3">Deluxe</span></div><div class="capacity-info"><span>Total Capacity: 6</span><br><span>Available: 6</span></div></div>
      </div>
```

I want to change the name of class of the div which is selected or clicked and the rest of the div should contain original class "btn-custom-primary".
The above code is not working... Please help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-custom').click(function() { 
    console.log("test");
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.btn-custom').removeClass('btn-custom-selected').addClass("btn-custom-primary");
    $(this).removeClass("btn-custom-primary").addClass('btn-custom-selected');
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-custom').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.btn-custom').removeClass('btn-custom-selected').addClass("btn-custom-primary");
    $(this).removeClass("btn-custom-primary").addClass('btn-custom-selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-custom-selected {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rooms-information" class="form-group">
  <div id="3ccd3803-a8ba-0328-cf9d-28bb72abbcae" class="btn-custom btn-custom-primary col-md-4 room-no-6">
    <div class="room-info-section"><span>Room No.: 6</span><br><span id="room0">Deluxe</span></div>
    <div class="capacity-info"><span>Total Capacity: 8</span><br><span>Available: 8</span></div>
  </div>
  <div id="4908ec27-b2ca-7bf7-de3d-83181d5c41a6" class="btn-custom btn-custom-primary col-md-4 room-no-1">
    <div class="room-info-section"><span>Room No.: 1</span><br><span id="room1">Deluxe</span></div>
    <div class="capacity-info"><span>Total Capacity: 4</span><br><span>Available: 4</span></div>
  </div>
  <div id="531709a7-6bc2-ddbe-3f3d-1642b7d70929" class="btn-custom btn-custom-primary col-md-4 room-no-3">
    <div class="room-info-section"><span>Room No.: 3</span><br><span id="room2">Simple</span></div>
    <div class="capacity-info"><span>Total Capacity: 4</span><br><span>Available: 4</span></div>
  </div>
  <div id="cac24d40-0e85-6707-9797-5f9f3449ecf8" class="btn-custom btn-custom-primary col-md-4 room-no-4">
    <div class="room-info-section"><span>Room No.: 4</span><br><span id="room3">Deluxe</span></div>
    <div class="capacity-info"><span>Total Capacity: 6</span><br><span>Available: 6</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used ur code, the code does not work. I think the click is not getting triggered. Also i need id of the div for further use

Comment: I've readded the ID, I cant tell you why the click dont work, try check the console for erros

Comment: I have debugged this on console and the actual reason is button is not triggered. 4

Comment: My click function is no different than your click function. try add `console.log("test")` inside your click event and see if it shows in the console.

Comment: Nope, it does not display test in console. I can tell u one thing that all buttons(divs) inside "rooms-information" div are created on the change event of a select tag programitically.

Comment: try use `$(document).on('click','.btn-custom',function(){`

Comment: Now it is getting triggered

Comment: @NidaAmin It becuase your `.btn-custom` don't exist in the DOM, so you have to do it this way. If the answer helped you and It resolved your problems please feel free to mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

You are doing much more than required. When clicking on some element you'll its reference with `$(this)` in handler function in jQuery. And there you can just add whatever class you want for the specific clicked element.

All the other divs already have class `btn-custom-primary`. So you don't need to add it the second time

```
$('.btn-custom').click(function() {
     $(this).removeClass('btn-custom-primary').addClass('btn-custom-selected');
});
```